# Simple Sinatra Portfolio Site

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Basically, I just want to ask how to approach making a simple site in Sinatra.

But if possible;

1. It needs a simple authentication for a single admin.
2. In a nutshell, the admin sets what's on the main page, like what's the content.
3. The content is basically piped from the admin page, so no database is needed, if it's not possible then what ORM gets me up and running immediately?

Also, I'm planning to host it on Heroku, what limitation will I encounter?

Thanks, beforehand for the time spared.

Comment: Will it be you adding the content or another user? If it's you, deploying new versions of a static site to Heroku would be much easier than writing admin authentication and content management.

Comment: Depends, if the complexity outweigh the benefit then, I'll be the one adding the content. What I want is a simple CM for static front-end, since it's only portfolio and showcase stuff.

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/admin/login' do
  # login
end
```

And go!

I would try [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) for your ORM.

You need a place to store your data. You cannot just "pipe" it from another page.

Comment: Too bad. . . , How about the simple authentication?